# Magic the Gathering Storyline Help

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I got back into Magic around the Return to Ravnica block. I'm familiar with the story from then until now.

They're traveling back to Dominaria, and I feel like I'm missing some of the story. It also seems like there's a lot of material to cover. What and how much do I need to know? Where should I start?

Comment: Mind you I have not read this yet; but this is related to your question and may provide some of the details you are looking for: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159963/how-can-i-catch-up-with-the-story-in-magic-the-gathering